# Display Images in ImageAdapter (GridView) while downloading

Tags: java, android, image, gridview

I'm making an application that reads a bunch of images URL on a JSON string.  With a new thread the app downloads the images to a specific directory.  Then there is a "gallery" based on a GridView with an ImageAdapter that displays all the files.  The thing is that it takes too long the first time to download all the images.

My goal is to display the images while they are downloading.  Right now the user has to go back and then enter again in the gallery to view the new images.  Until all the images are downloaded.

If someone has a workaround for this, let me know.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your images are downloaded call notifydatasetchanged on the adapter. This can be done either after every image or a set of images.

Edit : Assuming you are calling the thread in MainActivity and the adapter is being called in the Display Activity , you can have the downloading thread call a listener, defined in the Display activity which calls notifydatasetchanged.

Also I am hoping each image is downloaded in a separate thread :-)

Comment: Sounds good, but I don't see how can I do it.  Here is the scenario.  There is a Main Menu on the Main activity.  I have an array of 100 images Urls to download.  In that activity runs a new thread that starts the downloads of the images.  If the users click one icon that says gallery.  The app will display the images that are in the array.  Is there any way from that downloading thread, update the ImageAdapter from the 2nd activity that is the Gallery?

Comment: Are the images downloaded in individual threads? You can use a listener to notify the adapter or the activity managing the adapter.

Comment: Yes, There is a thread just for the downloading of the images.  Inclusive the display is in another activity.  MainActivity calls a new thread for the downloads, an item of a gridview creates a new activity for the gallery.  This new activiy is the one that has the ImageAdapter.  The original thread was created in the Main Activity.  Can I accomplish that with a listener?